# Split large textfile to multiple files based on a list of keywords in python

Tags: python, split, keyword

I am new to python. I am stuck at my homework. I am trying to split a 10,000 lines of text file into multiple files based on a list of keywords.

input.txt looks something like this:

```
 Name: Apple
 Type: Fruits
 Description:...

 Name: Orange
 Type: Fruits
 Description:...

 Name: Yellow
 Type: Colour
 Description:...

 Name: Apple
 Type: Fruits
 Description:...

 Name: Orange
 Type: Fruits
 Description:...

 Name: Yellow
 Type: Colour
 Description:...
```

Keywords:

```
Apple
Orange
Yellow
```

Expected output files :

Apple.txt

```
 Type: Fruits
 Description:
```

0range.txt

```
 Type: Fruits
 Description:
```

Yellow.txt

```
 Type: Colour
 Description:
```

But my current codes only able to split if the key is 'Apple'. I am not sure how to modify it to a  range of keywords.

```
key = ['Apple']

outfile = None
fno = 0
lno = 0

with open('input.txt') as infile:
    while line := infile.readline():
        lno += 1
        if outfile is None:
            fno += 1
            outfile = open(f'{fno}.txt', 'w')
        outfile.write(line)
        
        if key in line:
            print(f'"{key}" found in line {lno}')
            outfile.close()
            outfile = None
if outfile:
    outfile.close()
```

Edit: It should print the first record for each keyword.

Comment: Why is the expected output a single record even when the input file contains multiple records? Is the requirement to print the first, the last, or all unique records for each keyword? The example is probably too simple, and/or you have not captured all the requirements.

Comment: Hi My mistake. It should prints the first record for each keyword in a text file.

Comment: I'm thinking a `set` is a good data-structure for holding the keywords that you have already seen, because sets don't allow duplicates and testing membership is fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat more idiomatic version of your code. It does not hardcode a list of keywords; it simply picks up whatever comes after `Name:`

```
seen = set()
outfile = None

with open('input.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith(' Name: '):
            keyword = line[len(' Name: '):-1]
            if keyword not in seen:
                outfile = open(f'{keyword}.txt', 'w')
                seen.add(keyword)
        if outfile is not None:
            if line.strip() == '':
                outfile.close()
                outfile = None
            else:
                outfile.write(line)
if outfile is not None:
    outfile.close()
```

You were never doing anything useful with `lno` but if you wanted it for some reason, the idiomatic way to get line numbers is

```
    for lno, line in enumerate(infile, start=1):
```

Your sample `input.txt` shows a space at the beginning of each line. If that was incorrectly transcribed, obviously adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Since each record is separated by a blank line, a cleaner approach would be to read the first line of each record for a name, and use the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function with newline as a sentinel to read the rest of the record, which is then written to a file under the name if the name is a keyword:

```
keywords = {'Apple', 'Orange', 'Yellow'}

with open('input.txt') as file:
    while keywords and (name := next(file, ': ').split(': ', 1)[-1]):
        rest = list(iter(file.__next__, '\n'))
        if name in keywords:
            keywords.remove(name)
            with open(name + '.txt', 'w') as output:
                output.writelines(rest)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/SiennaOrderlyCygwin